# How to perform a update that won't lock other queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a potentially large update statement that changes a boolean flag and timestamp column on a table.

This operation may update a few thousand rows in a table that might have a few million rows.

The update operation shouldn't lock the table, and I am willing totally fine if other queries that might be running at the same time get stale data.

The goal is to perform the update statement in a way that won't effect other read operations (or even updates if that is possible).

In this situation, it is fine if read operations get incorrect values for the boolean flag and timestamp column while the update statement is processing.

Does postgresql have any query optimizations for an update statement that I can use given the above loose requirements?

Comment: Writers don't block readers in Postgres and readers don't block writers. Postgres will only lock the rows that you update and will prevent other sessions of updating them. An update statement will never lock the whole table (unless you update all rows, but then the table can still be queried) No select statement will be blocked. This is how Postgres works, there is nothing you need to do.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh I see, curious, do you know if mysql behaves the same way?

Comment: I think yes (there might be some lock-escalation going on, but I'm not sure. I hardly ever have to use MySQL). But I'd say any modern DBMS will (should) behave that way.

Comment: @publicstatic In MySQL it depends on the storage engine. If you're using InnoDB then IIRC it's similar to PostgreSQL. If you're using MyISAM then ... well, you're stuffed.

Answer (score 0):

As @a_horse_with_no_name notes, an `UPDATE` (or `INSERT` or `DELETE`) doesn't prevent concurrent `SELECT`s in PostgreSQL, unless those `SELECT`s do explicit row locking with `FOR UPDATE` or `FOR SHARE`.

So you can continue to `SELECT` from the table while the update runs. The `SELECT` will just see the old values.

Any `UPDATE`s or `DELETE`s that affect the rows already being `UPDATE`d will be *blocked* on a row lock until the prior `UPDATE` completes. However, there's a wrinkle with update ordering here.

If your big update is scanning the table in order, updating each row as it goes, and then you do another small `UPDATE` that scans the table in some other order to choose rows to update, you can land up with a deadlock. The big update might have locked the row with id=1000, and be trying to lock the row with id=1001. But your newer small update already has a lock on id=1001 and is trying to obtain a lock on id=1000. Neither can ever get the lock they want, so they're stuck. PostgreSQL detects this and aborts one of the statements with a deadlock detection error. There is *no guarantee* which statement will be aborted.

To mitigate this, I recommend breaking your big `UPDATE` into a series of small `UPDATE`s if possible, each over a range of values. That'll also reduce the amount of extra workspace the database must allocate in the table to store the new versions of the rows until the update finishes and it can clean out the old ones.

I expect MySQL+InnoDB to behave similarly. MySQL+MyISAM will just lock the table when you do the `UPDATE`, but you shouldn't be using MyISAM anyway.